# Is there anything different between R.merge vs composing with rest operator?

Tags: ramda.js

Is there any advantage of use R.merge over composing with the rest operator?

```
const a = {name: 'john', job: 'developer'};
const b = {name: 'peter', commute: 'bike', address: {city: 'San Francisco'}};
const c = {...a, ...b};
console.log('rest', c);
const d = R.merge(a, b);
console.log('R.merge', d);
```

c and d appear to be the same.

Are there any cases where the rest operator won't work while R.merge will?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current implementation of `R.merge` is effectively `R.curry((l, r) => Object.assign({}, l, r))` (albeit polyfilled when necessary), so when fully applied it will behave the same as the rest operator in your example.

The main difference being that `R.merge` is curried, allowing for partial application. It can also be useful when operating in environments where the rest operator (or `Object.assign`) isn't available.

So if you don't require partial application and have the the rest operator natively available to you, then there is little benefit to use `R.merge(a, b)` over `{...a, ...b}`.

Answer (score 2):

As well as the (absolutely correct and relevant) answer from Scott Christopher, there is also another way in which the two differ.  `merge` is a *function*.  `{...a, ...b}` is an *expression*.

One of the important features of Javascript is that functions are first class citizens: you can pass them to and return them from functions.  They can be the values of variables, or properties of objects.  The same is not true of expressions.  So to have a true equivalence, it would be one between

```
merge
```

and

```
(a, b) => ({...a, ...b})
```

And even that does not capture the curried nature of `R.merge` that Scott discusses.

Of course this makes no difference for a one-off expression, but when you're passing the function around, `merge` might be clearer to read.